# How to set the first item as selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have 2 ListView controls here, let's say Listview1 and Listview2, respectively. What I would like to achieve is that I want the first item in Listview2 to be selected & highlighted whenever Listview1's SelectionChanged event is triggered.

I have tried to use the following line of code to make it happened but I guess it's not correct.

```
private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    Listview2.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

The first item in Listview2 is still not selected & highlighted. Can anyone help? Thanks very much in advance.

Edit:
That line is correct. It didn't work because I placed it before the line of code that was doing dynamic loading. No wonder.... :)

Comment: Are you dynamically loading the contents of the second view?  If so, you need to hold on changing the index until after it is loaded.  Right now, you just have a race condition and you're losing.

Comment: The code you posted should work. Did you set a breakpoint to verify the posted code is being executed? What else is going on - e.g. databinding, updating the items, anything like that?

Comment: @JefMercado: This sounds like the only reasonable answer to me, how about posting it as such?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. You just inspired me :D I got it working now.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Told ya! (*I know you didn't get much of a chance to react yet :P*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this code and its running fine.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        try  
        {      
            //listView.Focus();              
            listView2.Items[0].Selected = true;  
        }  
        catch { }  
    }
```

But after running its output when i select the first item in "listView1" the item of "listView2" is selected but you can not see it because the focus on Listview1. When you click on the listView2 then you will see a blink of selected item. Ithink there is no way to focus on two listview at the same time. When you will uncomment the "listView.Focus()" then you will see that the selected item is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{    
((ListViewItem)Listview2.Items[0].Selected) = true;
}
```

Comment: The error message says, "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Need to cast it to `ListViewItem` First, `((ListViewItem)Listview2.Items[0].Selected) = true;` but it wont help..

Comment: well still get the same error if I cast it to ListViewItem object type. Weird. :(

Comment: `((ListViewItem)Listview2.Items[0]).Selected = true`

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.Selected' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

Comment: @woodykiddy: `IsSelected` is the property you want, in any case that is not a safe method for selection since the Items can be anything, not just `ListViewItems` (e.g. if the ListView is data-bound).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any problem with your code. I think you cannot see the highlighting because ListView2 items are not focused. Make the item Focused and see.

Comment: I tested his code, also added some plus the focus thing and nothing happened!

Comment: I am still pretty new to wpf, and I couldn't find the HideSelection Property in Listview. Can you please tell me how I am able to set its value to false here? Thanks, CharithJ.

Comment: @Rami : HideSelection is off?

Comment: @WoodyKiddy : HideSelection Propery of the ListView2 can be set false by using the Properties Window. It's true by default as I remember.

Comment: @CharithJ Are you thinking Winforms? If the WPF ListView has a HideSelection property, it's pretty well-hidden.

Comment: Are you sure that `HideSelection` exists?

Comment: I think that property is available for Windows.Forms not WPF though. I don't think we can call this property in WPF, can we?

Comment: I am sorry yes, that property is not available for WPF. I just tested this scenario and it works fine.